# How can I convert string to dict or list?

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have strings such as:

`'[1, 2, 3]'`

and

`"{'a': 1, 'b': 2}"`

How do I convert them to list/dict?

Someone mentions that `ast.literal_eval` or `eval` can parse a string that converts to list/dict.

What's the difference between `ast.literal_eval` and `eval`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`ast.literal_eval` parses 'abstract syntax trees.' You nearly have json there, for which you could use `json.loads`, but you need double quotes, not single quotes, for dictionary keys to be valid.

```
import ast

result = ast.literal_eval("{'a': 1, 'b': 2}")
assert type(result) is dict

result = ast.literal_eval("[1, 2, 3]")
assert type(result) is list
```

As a plus, this has none of the risk of `eval`, because it doesn't get into the business of evaluating functions. `eval("subprocess.call(['sudo', 'rm', '-rf', '/'])")` could remove your root directory, but `ast.literal_eval("subprocess.call(['sudo', 'rm', '-rf', '/'])")` fails predictably, with your file system intact.

Answer (score 7):

Use the eval function:

```
l = eval('[1, 2, 3]')

d = eval("{'a':1, 'b': 2}")
```

Just make sure you know where these strings came from and that you aren't allowing user input to be evaluated and do something malicious.

Answer (score 3):

**python script to convert this string to dict : -**

```
import json

inp_string = '{"1":"one", "2":"two"}'
out = json.loads(inp_string)
print out["1"]
```

O/P is like :

```
"one"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert string to list/dict by `ast.literal_eval()` or `eval()` function. `ast.literal_eval()` only considers a small subset of Python's syntax to be valid:

> The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python
>   literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans,
>   and None.

Passing `__import__('os').system('rm -rf /')` into `ast.literal_eval()` will raise an error, but `eval()` will happily wipe your drive.

Since it looks like you're only letting the user input a plain dictionary, use `ast.literal_eval()`. It safely does what you want and nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

You can `eval()` but only with safe data. Otherwise, if you parse unsafe data, take a look into safer `ast.literal_eval()`.

JSON parser is also a possibility, most of python dicts and lists have the same syntax.